# How can I move my Dynamic Data folder?

Tags: asp.net, git, dynamic-data, msysgit

I accidentally moved my `Dynamic Data` folder into my `Images` folder.  The project still compiles, but it's just not right.  However, when I try to move it back to the root in Visual Studio, I get an error that the destination folder already exists.  If I move `Dynamic Data` back to the root outside of Visual Studio, the project no longer compiles because the compiler can't find any dynamic data files.

My infancy with git prompted me to ask here before embarking on an unpleasant 2am quest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Close visual studio.

Go to the project folder in windows explorer. Is there a DD folder in the root? What does it contain? Move the DD folder in the root a temp location.

Move the DD folder under images to the root location. Open your .proj file and change the location of the DD folder to the one in root.

Finally open the solution in Visual studio.

Comment: Thanks, I just in fact did that.  I was initially ambushed by the VS search not finding the file references, for all files solution wide.  I suspect '\' is a dodgy character to the searc, even without wildcards.